# Block Shellshock/Bashdoor with htaccess?

Tags: htaccess

How do I block Shellshock, also known as Bashdoor, in htaccess?

Using a Shared Host, add a Block for User-Agent: "uname"

```
Host: 46.105.126.165
Http Code:/?x=()
Date: Jun 26 07:38:49
Http Version: {Size in Bytes: };
Referer: echo
Status: 0
Agent: Content-type:text/plain;echo;echo;echo M`expr 1330 + 7`H;/bin/uname -a;echo @ HTTP/1.0 403 - () { :; }; echo Content-type:text/plain;echo;echo;echo M`expr 1330 + 7`H;/bin/uname -a;echo @ () { :; }; echo Content-type:text/plain;echo;echo;echo M`expr 1330 + 7`H;/bin/uname -a;echo @
```

Comment: Are you vulnerable??

Comment: I don't know? 
I tracked down what /?x=() was & scoured for htaccess code unsuccessfully.

Comment: Check out https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shellshock_(software_bug) and pay attention to the CVE notices half way down. There are some tests you can run to know. You will want to check this. This is something that if not fixed right away you will not only get hacked in the worst way, but possibly destroyed.

Comment: I was forbidden 8)  I changed my Hotlinking code back to RewriteCond from SetEnvIfNoCase for a Whitelisted no-hotlinking.gif may have made the difference?

Comment: These are bash vulnerabilities. You would check them in a bash session through shell (SSH). Please know that bash is compiled into so much code, the system can be vulnerable is soooooo many ways that it is just a matter of time- not just Apache- though that is a common way in.

Comment: my site does not use SSH

Comment: I wonder how you can check the version of bash then? Huh.

Comment: Are you running a control panel that gives you terminal access?

Comment: simple cut-n-paste

Comment: Huh. There is this: http://shellshock.brandonpotter.com/ Scary warning on this one. As well, you can check to see if the OS version has the updated bash. Some OSs had the bash fixed update. One other thing is to simply check with your hosts tech support. I rather suspect you are okay since this was such a HUGE vulnerability. Still, you want to check.

Comment: You can check your OS version against a simple Google search such as this one *shellshock ubuntu version*.

Comment: No T'access & I'm not sure about trusting brandon potter although he is using Microsoft Corp network...

Comment: Okay. I would call tech support for your host quickly. I am sure they will tell you you are fine... otherwise, I would be changing hosts quickly!! ;-) Meanwhile, if you are not vulnerable, I would only try and block these if they really really annoy you. Even then, it may be better to block on IP addresses rather than chase blocking by terms found in the agent string. Doing a search.

Comment: That is why deny 46 is there 8);  but some buggers were getting through somehow.  That's why my old hotlinking code went back up.  It's better to block a few innocents in this case...

Comment: I found this: http://www.skepticism.us/2015/04/configuring-wordpress-to-reject-shellshock-attacks/ There are some .htaccess rules here. There may be more... but it seems that this is not a hot issue if patched.

Comment: I ran the bash test -  8)

Comment: All good then??

Comment: Funny I found that same site earlier today... My site is NOT on CMS 8)

Comment: Good for now...

Comment: I am not sure how effective the above linked code is, but it is a start if you want to try it. I let these attack go on my site knowing that nothing would happen. Again, I think I would blocks IPs first. This probably will not last too long if you are annoyed enough anything you do could be temporary.

Comment: My site appears secure for now - Thanks for all the advice 8)

Answer (score 1):

Time for an official answer.

What I learned is that hackers like to try to exploit the shell shock bug with variants. They like to try to use lines containing `(){}` and `( ){:;}` and similar, where the only differences for the most part are the number of spaces between each character.

It's a matter of when apache writes data to the system's environment table (for example: setting an environment variable such as REQUEST_URI) that counts. If apache writes data before processing the mod_rewrite module, then configuring .htaccess using RewriteRule directives will have no effect.

The best thing to do is to access SSH (server shell) and enter commands to see if your system is vulnerable and if it is, then it needs to be patched.

See https://access.redhat.com/articles/1200223 for instructions on commands to type into the shell.

If you are on shared hosting or you have no access to SSH or a shell, then contact the administrator of your hosting environment and tell them to check the server for the vulnerability and fix as necessary.

Since you are concerned about this, what you should do ASAP is back up every piece of valuable website content you have along with any databases you have running just in case a hacker ends up trashing the server.